# Are questions on yaml for testng coding on topic?

Tags: support, site-scope

I wanted to ask a question on structuring common and test-specific data in yaml files for using with DataProviders in TestNG. However, there is no tag for [yaml](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yaml) so I don't know if this belongs on SQA or SO.

Also, going through the [testng](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testng) questions there are several with code examples. So I expect that code questions on any testing framework (TestNG, Cucumber, Karate) should be allowed? Or do I need to consider if it is somehow not specific to software QE and post those on SO/elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Questions on YAML are on-topic when they involve a testing tool - for that I would consider whether you would get a better response from SO or here.

Coding questions on any testing framework are on-topic. What I have seen is that the coding questions here tend to be more "beginner-level", possibly because as test specialists many of us don't have the deep coding experience of the SO regulars.